# IndexError: list index out of range for list of lists in for loop

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop, file-io

I've looked at the other questions posted on the site about index error, but       I'm still not understanding how to fix my own code. Im a beginner when it comes to Python. Based on the users input, I want to check if that input lies in the fourth position of each line in the list of lists.

Here's the code:

```
#create a list of lists from the missionPlan.txt
from __future__ import with_statement

listoflists = []
with open("missionPlan.txt", "r") as f:
    results = [elem for elem in f.read().split('\n') if elem]
    for result in results:
        listoflists.append(result.split())
#print(listoflists)
#print(listoflists[2][3])

choice = int(input('Which command would you like to alter: '))
i = 0
for rows in listoflists:
    while i < len(listoflists):
        if listoflists[i][3]==choice:
            print (listoflists[i][0])

        i += 1
```

This is the error I keep getting:

> not getting inside the if statement

Comment: Firstly, `choice` is already an integer, so you don't need `int(choice)` again. Also, your for loop is wrong. You set `i=0` every time right after you add one to it, so it's always zero. Fix your indentation maybe?

Comment: I've made the suggested changes and its still giving me the same error @mbomb007

Comment: You don't need stackoverflow; you can solve this yourself. Either `i` is too big, or the `3` is too big. Put in some print statements to see what the data is, then figure out which number is too big. Don't forget: counting starts at zero, so if the list has three items, the biggest index you can use is 2.

Comment: For Guido's sake, please replace listoflists[i] by num inside your loop... (and don't call it num if it is a list and erase num+=1)
Also please add a blank line after Here's the code (for better SO formatting)

Comment: But don't use list as a variable name (you don't want to overwrite it).
And please choose between while and for loops.

Comment: Have you checked that all your lines have at least 4 "words"? Add for example if len(result.split()) < 4: print('a', result,'b')

Comment: the text file is formatted like an excel spreadsheet separated by four spaces. I'm trying to search for a number, not word. Do you think thats the problem? Is my code looking for a word instead of a number?

Answer (score 0):

So, I *think* this is what you're trying to do - find any line in your "missionPlan.txt" where the 4th word (after splitting on whitespace) matches the number that was input, and print the first word of such lines.

If that is indeed accurate, then perhaps something along this line would be a better approach.

```
choice = int(input('Which command would you like to alter: '))

allrecords = []

with open("missionPlan.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:

        words = line.split()
        allrecords.append(words)

        try:
            if len(words) > 3 and int(words[3]) == choice:
                print words[0]
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Also, if, as your tags suggest, you are using Python 3.x, I'm fairly certain the `from __future__ import with_statement` isn't particularly necessary...

EDIT: added a couple lines based on comments below. Now in addition to examining every line as it's read, and printing the first field from every line that has a fourth field matching the input, it gathers each line into the `allrecords` list, split into separate words as a list - corresponding to the original questions `listoflists`. This will enable further processing on the file later on in the code. Also fixed one glaring mistake - need to split `line` into `words`, not `f`...

Also, to answer your "I cant seem to get inside that if statement" observation - that's because you're comparing a string (`listoflists[i][3]`) with an integer (`choice`). The code above addresses both that comparison mismatch and the check for there actually being enough words in a line to do the comparison meaningfully...

Comment: that's what I am trying to do but not exactly. I'm searching for a number in the 4th element of every line within the list of lists, and comparing that number to the inputted. The text file looks something like this:

Comment: 0     1     0     12     0     0     0     0     33.545     45.35     154.000     1                                                            1     0     3     11     1     0     0     0     12.101     222.0     451.222     1            2     4     4      4       0    0      0     0    45.222     457.21   4444444     4

Comment: @Allie Given the code you posted, though, isn't your "list of lists" simply a list of the result of splitting each line of the original file into a list of fields? The above code avoids building that "list of lists", but looks at the fourth field of each line in turn... Or do you need that "list of lists" for later processing?

Comment: yes the "list of lists" will be used for later processing. Within the second for loop, I do actually want to look at the fourth field in each line, but I cant seem to get inside that if statement. I want to be able to display every line that has the input as the fourth field, then eventually store those lines in a list as well